# How full is my ZFS pool? (not sure how to read command output)

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I'm using ZFS on FreeBSD to store several TB of data.

If stored as non-dedup, about 25% of the raw data would be unique enough that compression helps but dedup is wasted.

The other 75% contains a lot of dedup-able data, and I've had ratios of 2x - 8x with this dataset in the past. So my NAS was specced from the start to be able to handle compressed dedup if needed: 96GB 2400 ECC (more can be added if stats show dedup table pressure), 3.5GHz quad core Xeon, mirrored disks, NVMe L2ARC, and Intel P3700 NVMe ZIL.

The raw pool capacity is currently 22 GB before formatting (3 x 6TB vdevs + 1 x 4TB vdev) and intuitively I think I'm physically using about 7 - 14 TB of it right now. It contains both Samba file share datasets and fixed-size ESXi iSCSI zvols (mostly empty, at least one sparse). But because I don't understand the difference between these outputs, they are confusing me, and I'm not sure how much free space I actually have, and therefore whether I want to add more disks to keep it below my target of 65% usage:

**# zpool list -v**

```
NAME                                     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank                                    19.9T  14.0T  5.93T         -    53%    70%  2.30x  ONLINE  /mnt
  mirror                                5.44T  4.18T  1.26T         -    59%    76%
    gptid/6c62bc1a-0b7b-11e7-86ae-000743144400      -      -      -         -      -      -
    gptid/94cad523-0b45-11e7-86ae-000743144400      -      -      -         -      -      -
  mirror                                5.41T  4.38T  1.03T         -    62%    80%
    ada0p2                                  -      -      -         -      -      -
    gptid/e619dab7-03f1-11e7-8f93-000743144400      -      -      -         -      -      -
  mirror                                5.44T  4.12T  1.32T         -    56%    75%
    gptid/c68f80ae-01da-11e7-b762-000743144400      -      -      -         -      -      -
    da0                                     -      -      -         -      -      -
    da1                                     -      -      -         -      -      -
  mirror                                3.62T  1.31T  2.32T         -    29%    36%
    da3                                     -      -      -         -      -      -
    da4                                     -      -      -         -      -      -
```

**# zdb -bDDD tank**

```
DDT-sha256-zap-duplicate: 39468847 entries, size 588 on disk, 190 in core

     [duplicate bucket data cut as it isn't relevant and repeats in the totals below]

DDT-sha256-zap-unique: 60941882 entries, size 526 on disk, 170 in core

bucket              allocated                       referenced
______   ______________________________   ______________________________
refcnt   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE
------   ------   -----   -----   -----   ------   -----   -----   -----
     1    58.1M   1.21T    964G   1005G    58.1M   1.21T    964G   1005G
     2    25.0M   1.10T    784G    807G    58.5M   2.69T   1.87T   1.92T
     4    10.4M    393G    274G    282G    48.4M   1.85T   1.29T   1.34T
     8    1.70M   51.1G   37.7G   39.7G    16.5M    487G    353G    372G
    16     456K   9.85G   5.73G   6.44G    10.1M    212G    121G    138G
    32    67.0K   1.73G    998M   1.07G    2.77M   77.1G   44.6G   48.6G
    64    23.7K    455M    327M    350M    1.98M   36.1G   25.8G   27.7G
   128    3.47K   75.7M   48.0M   54.5M     557K   12.1G   7.68G   8.70G
   256      610   46.9M   12.3M   13.6M     216K   16.9G   4.14G   4.61G
   512      211   14.8M   2.46M   3.01M     145K   10.2G   1.72G   2.10G
    1K       57   1.10M     38K    228K    77.7K   1.45G   49.3M    311M
    2K       42    456K     22K    168K     118K   1.17G   61.3M    474M
    4K       18    108K      9K     72K     104K    574M   52.1M    417M
    8K       11    128K   5.50K     44K     117K   1.29G   58.3M    467M
   16K        7    152K      4K     28K     155K   2.60G   85.6M    619M
  128K        1     16K     512      4K     137K   2.14G   68.4M    548M
  256K        1      4K     512      4K     302K   1.18G    151M   1.18G
 Total    95.8M   2.76T   2.02T   2.09T     198M   6.59T   4.65T   4.83T

dedup = 2.31, compress = 1.42, copies = 1.04, dedup * compress / copies = 3.15
```

- **The first output** seems to be saying that the formatted pool capacity is 19.9TB (sounds about right) of which **space in use is around 14TB** and 5.93TB is spare. If so, I'll add more disks.
- **The second output** seems to be saying that the actual **allocated physical space is around 2.02TB** (or 6.59TB with 3.15x saving due to compression+dedup).

The two numbers are wildly different, and I don't understand how to reconcile them.

Hint appreciated please!

Comment: You may take a look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582005/zpool-list-vs-zfs-list-why-free-space-is-10x-different#582383

Answer (score 0):

> The two numbers are wildly different, and I don't understand how to reconcile them.
>
> Hint appreciated please!

The `zpool` output is correct.

The other command you might be interested in is `zfs list`.

Comment: But how do these two outputs _reconcile_? Why are the zbd outputs so different?

Comment: The purpose of the `zpool` and `zfs` commands is to allow the administrator/user to make changes and get status information.  The purpose of the `zdb` command is to provide an view of the inner workings of the file-system.  While I'm sure that the `zdb` command can be used to provide information on the available space in the pool/file-system, it would require an in-depth understanding of the ZFS structures to know that you're requesting/receiving the correct information, and to know how to interpret the information you receive.

Comment: I'm not that bad at in-depth :) zdb listed block count by size, physical count and logical reference in the pool. Total blocks x size (x refcount) should roughly be close to physical+logical space used. Why don't either of these even approximately match the actual used space in the pool? By a rather large factor (many times over). The space used should, probably, map onto blocks one way or another. So how do the 2 figures reconcile? Seems a very clear question. If they don't, what accounts for the difference and why isn't that amount of TB somewhere in the blocks allocated/referenced?

Comment: Peter - you may not mean it but your comment above feels as if it comes over as _"its job is to help administrators and I'm sure it can help them, but you would need in depth knowledge to understand it and I don't know if you would understand it so this is clearly knowledge you shouldn't worry yourself over, leave it to a sysadmin and go back to Lego"_. You might not mean it as incredibly condescending but it is. If you know, please explain. If not, your comment hasn't added anything anyway. My question is how zdb's blocks , size x refs info reconciles to zpool's  physical/logical volume size

Comment: Stilez - I feel that `zdb` is a developer tool, not an admin tool.  I've been administering ZFS pools (up to 150TB) for eight years, under Solaris, Linux and FreeBSD, and I've only used `zdb` once (under FreeBSD to make sure my settings were accepted).  I'm sorry, but I don't understand the ZFS internals enough to help you translate the `zdb` output to match the `zpool` or `zfs` output.  What I **do** know is that the `zpool` and `zfs` commands provide correct output, and that their values should be very close with mirrors (not so close with RAID-Z1/2/3, due to what they actually look at).

Answer (score 0):

The definitive way to check how full your pool is, is to ask it:

```
$ zpool get capacity tank
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
tank      capacity  60%    -
```

If you prefer, you can do the math yourself:

```
$ zpool get -p allocated,size tank
NAME      PROPERTY   VALUE         SOURCE
tank      allocated  596675149824  -
tank      size       987842478080  -
$ bc 
scale=4
59667514982400/987842478080
60.4018
```